# How do time reversal and parity inversion act on a Majorana spinor in QFT?

Tags: special-relativity, representation-theory, spinors, parity, time-reversal-symmetry

Dirac particles are not the same Majorana particles. However, in the simple Lorentz group (boost and rotations, but no parity or time flips), they transform the same way. Particles in QFT were defined as one-to-one with irreducible representations of the Lorentz group, so it must be that in the *general* Lorentz group, Majorana particles transform differently than Dirac.

I tried searching for the Majorana transformation properties to no avail. Does anyone have an answer or source for how Majorana particles transform under parity and/or time reversal, in a way that is clearly not unitarily equivalent to how Dirac particles transform?

Edit: Thanks to clarifications by knzhou, I'd be interested in the transformation laws of states, not fields. The heart of the question was to see exactly how Dirac & Majorana do not transform via the same representation of the Lorentz group. I don't see any difference according to the definitions in Weinberg.

Comment: Do you mean the transformations of Majorana fields, or the particles created by Majorana fields? There's a crucial difference.

Comment: True, I mean Majorana fields, thanks for the distinction

Comment: Majorana fields transform just like Dirac fields. That's half of the point of even using Majorana fields in the first place -- it behaves the same way as something you already know.

Comment: Hmm, so the notion of particles being in 1-to-1 correspondence with irreps of the Lorentz group is not actually true?

Comment: Fields correspond to representations of the Lorentz group, particles correspond to representations of the Poincare group. The particles associated with a Majorana field are different than those associated with a Dirac field.

Comment: At the level of representation theory, Majorana fields are in real representations, and hence lower-dimensional than Dirac fields. Which is why they are associated with fewer distinct particle Poincare irreps than Dirac fields, because the particle and antiparticle species are the same.

Comment: Sorry to redirect my question, but do you have a source for the trafo laws for particles then? I didn't realize that it was the state transformation laws, not the field transformation laws, that distinguish the particle types.

Comment: Massive Majorana particles simply live in the usual spin $1/2$ representation of the Poincare group. (It's not some new representation you haven't heard of!) The only special feature is that this representation is mapped to itself under $\hat{C}$. I don't have a good source for anything I'm saying. I've written several long answers on this site about particles vs. fields, and it's neglected in textbooks enough that I've often seen professors get it wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99215/discussion-between-doublefelix-and-knzhou).